# What is the replacement of DataTrigger in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, datatrigger, listboxitem, itemtemplate

I am working on windows phone 8 and i want to set styles on different-2 components in my ListBox control so after  Googling i have come to know it is possible through DataTriggers, i am trying in my Application to do same but it shows typo error in myApplication. ***So is there any replacement for DataTrigger in windows phone 8 ?***